# Construct a linear map R3→R3 which maps the xy-plane bijectively onto the plane spanned by (1,1,1) and (1,2,3)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I think we need a specific example. But I cannot find one so I am trying to work through the logic. So to my understanding, we must map vectors of the form (x,y,0) to vectors that are a linear combination of (1,1,1) and (1,2,3).

So we can say v $\in(x,y,0)$ and let v = $\sum a_ie_i$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis vectors of R^3. Now it follows by the property of a linear map that it is is completely determined by T($e_i$). So it makes sense to write v such that T(v) => $\sum a_i$T($e_i$). We are saying this must equal some vector that is span of (1,1,1) and (1,2,3).

But at this point I am having trouble because I am not able to define T($e_i$). Well, we know this is equal to some vector in the set spanned by (1,1,1) and (1,2,3). We know (1,1,1) and (1,2,3) forms the rest of the vectors so would T($e_1$) = (1,1,1) and T($e_2$) = (1,2,3)?

Now if this is the case, how do we even answer the question?

Comment: That’s a good start. Now complete the two bases and pair up the third vectors in each basis.

Comment: Sorry, which bases are you referring to? Are you saying solve for the scalars of v to get the two spanning vectors? And I don't really understand what you mean pair up the third vectors in each basis.

Comment: So maybe something like T(v) = $\sum a_i$T($e_i$)  = $a_1 (1,1,1) + a_2 (1,2,3) = x(1,1,1) + y(1,2,3).$

Comment: You still have to do something with the $z$-coordinate. The map you’ve built so far isn’t a bijection.

Comment: Umm, well yeah, it would just be 0(0,0,1). So at this point would x(1,1,1) + y(1,2,3) + 0(0,0,1) be the linear map needed?

Comment: @Sirlethian:  did you mean $x(1,1,1)+y(1,2,3)+\color{red}z(0,0,1)$ ?

Comment: But isn't $z$ just 0 because our domain vectors are of the form $(x,y,0)$?

Comment: Only elements of the form $(x,y,0)$ are mapped on to the plane spanned by $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$, but in order to define a map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3, $ you must define what it does to all elements of the domain $\mathbb R^3.$